# Should I include a separate section for publications on my resume if I've only published a single paper?

Tags: resume

I've just published my first work related paper, should I include it in a separate section on my resume or just list it as a bulletpoint in the experience section under a job? I work in industry not academia.

Comment: Is there an academic job where they will be looking for such a section?

Comment: No I work in industry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> should I include it in a separate section on my resume or just list it
>   as a bulletpoint in the experience section under a job?

If your work-related paper is being published outside the realm of your job, then it should be in a separate "Publications" section. Hopefully, you'll have more papers listed over time, and this is just the first.

If instead this paper is something solely within the company (such as in a company newsletter), then it should just be a bullet point under your job listing.

Answer (score 1):

I have the below in my resume, as is under the Education section:

> Education:
>
> Master's of Computer Science "university" "location"
>
> - Received "Outstanding achievement in Computer Science" Reward
> - Receive Scholarship in *this and that*

I would and will just include any future published papers as a new bullet point, as I believe published papers are basically academic.